# How to remove apostrophe ' from column?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to remove all apostrophe ' from my column but it showing me error..How to remove it..This is what i am trying to get it....

```
 `UPDATE `vm_seo_detail` SET `sd_t` = REPLACE(`sd_t`, 'Sanstha'''s', 'Sansthas');`
```

Comment: What do you try, and what is your error?

Comment: This update query is not working..i want to remove 's from it..ERROR:-You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"s', 'Sansthas')' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove *all* of `'`, use this:

```
update `vm_seo_detail`
set `sd_t` = REPLACE(`sd_t`, '''', '');
```

If it's the `’` character, try this:

```
update `vm_seo_detail`
set `sd_t` = REPLACE(`sd_t`, '’', '');
```

Comment: maybe it isnt ' character, may be it's the other one - ’ . there is a difference

Comment: it's apostrophe..but not able to remove it..is there any other way to replase it../

Comment: @Mohanish - Please try the second SQL in the answer.

Comment: @GurV-it's still there..no result

Comment: @Mohanish - Can you add a sample of the data in your question?

Comment: Mahila-Vikas-Sanstha's-Institute-of-Advance-Studies..It's like this..i want to remove ' .. from here.